# Why 2 is not smaller than 10 on Codeblocks?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I just worked to my final exam with simple codes; when I try to sorting strings, I face annoying error. Why 2 is not smaller than 10 on my CodeBlocks IDE but is smaller than 10 on real and onlinegdb.com?

This is the annoying code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define STR_SIZ 20

int main()
{
    char strArr[][STR_SIZ] = {"abc", "hdas", "sdfasf", "kakldf", "caksl", "casd", "keam", "cznjcx", "mnxzv", "jkalkds"};
    char minStr[STR_SIZ];
    strcpy(minStr, strArr[0]);
    int N = sizeof(strArr)/sizeof(minStr);
   // int N = 10;
    for(int x = 0; x < N-1; x++)
    {
        printf("%d", x);
        strcpy(minStr,strArr[x]);
        int j;
        for(j=1+x; j < 10; j++)
        {
            printf("%4d\n", j);
            int cmp = strcmp(strArr[j], minStr);
            if(cmp < 0)
                strcpy(minStr,strArr[j]);
        }
        char temp[STR_SIZ];
        strcpy(temp,strArr[x]);
        strcpy(strArr[x], minStr);
        strcpy(strArr[j], temp);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Output on onlinegdb.com:

```
0   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
1   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
2   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
3   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
4   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
5   6
   7
   8
   9
6   7
   8
   9
7   8
   9
8   9
```

Output on CodeBlocks:

```
0   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
1   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
2
```

PS: I just have used Codeblock in the morning and it was okey with executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strArr` has 10 elements.  At the end of your loop, you call `strcpy(strArr[j], temp);`.  This will write to `strArr[10]`, which is out of bounds and will overwrite some unknown memory.  Anything can happen after that.

You should save the `j` value when you copy a string into `minStr`.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, your code above prints this as your final string order with onlinegdb:

```
abc                                                                                                                                                                                  
caksl                                                                                                                                                                                
caksl                                                                                                                                                                                
caksl                                                                                                                                                                                
caksl                                                                                                                                                                                
casd                                                                                                                                                                                 
cznjcx                                                                                                                                                                               
cznjcx                                                                                                                                                                               
jkalkds                                                                                                                                                                              
jkalkds
```

So I think you have other problems as well.

try this

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define STR_SIZ 20

int main()
{
    char strArr[][STR_SIZ] = {"abc", "hdas", "sdfasf", "kakldf", "caksl", "casd", "keam", "cznjcx", "mnxzv", "jkalkds"};
    strcpy(minStr, strArr[0]);

    // Calculate the number of elements this way.
    const int N = sizeof(strArr)/sizeof(strArr[0]);

    // int N = 10;
    for(int x = 0; x < N-1; x++)
    {
        printf("%d", x);
        int j;
        for(j=1+x; j < N; j++)  // Use N here too!
        {
            printf("%4d\n", j);
            int cmp = strcmp(strArr[j], strArr[x]);
            if(cmp < 0)
            {
                // Do the swaps only when needed.
                char temp[STR_SIZ];
                strcpy(temp,strArr[x]);
                strcpy(strArr[x], strArr[j]);
                strcpy(strArr[j], temp);
            }
        }
    }
    // Verify result
    for(int x = 0; x < N; x++) printf("%s\n", strArr[x]);

    return 0;
}
```

I moved your swap into your if check and got rid of your minStr as it was not needed.  Notice how I calculate the N size too.  Honestly, you were close, but you needed to verify your output.

Comment: I knew my output is also wrong but I wonder why  2 is not smaller than 10, previous answer gave it to me. Your answer is explainatory and clear, I understood what should be. Thanks!